# How would a observe a property that is in a parent view?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have the following code:

```
App.PeopleView = Ember.View.extend
({
    templateName: 'people',

    people: Ember.ArrayController.create(
    {
        sortProperties:     ['lastName'],
        sortAscending:      true,
        contentBinding:     Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.Mapper.person')
    }),

    Sort: Ember.View.extend(
    {
        templateName: 'people/sort',

        isAscending: function()
        {
            alert('Here');

            var rootView = this.nearestWithProperty('people');
            return rootView.get('people').get('sortAscending');
        }
        .property('$root.people.sortAscending')
    })
});
```

I want to be able to set the `property()` on the `sortAscending` property, but it belongs in a parent view, and I don't know how to reference it. `$root` doesn't work, but that was my guess as to how it worked.

Comment: Good Guy Greg answers his own question: `.property('parentView.people.sortAscending')`

Comment: Good Guy Greg can add it as an answer rather than a comment. Cheers